# How to pass paramaters to remote script in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server

I am working on a declarative jenkins pipeline where I am trying to login to remote host and execute shell script. Below is the sample snippet. I want to know How to pass a parameter to my script.sh script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "argument $1"
```

below is the pipeline script

```
hosts = [“x.x.x”, “x.x.x”]
pipeline {
  agent { node { label 'docker' } }

  parameters {
    choice(name: 'stageparam', choices: ['build', 'deploy'], description: ‘xyz’)
    string(name: 'Username', defaultValue: ‘abc’, description: 'enter username')
  }

  
  stages {
    stage('Setup') {
      steps {
        script {
          pom = getPom(effective: false)
        }
      }
    }
   
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        script {

          def targetServers = null
          if (stageparam == "deploy") {
            targetServers = hosts
          } 

          targetServers.each { server ->
            echo "Server : ${server}"
            def remote = [:]
            remote.name = ‘server’
            remote.host = server
            remote.user = Username
            def pass = passwordParameter description: "Enter password for user ${remote.user} "
            remote.password = pass
            remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            stage('Remote SSH') {
                         sshPut remote: remote, from: ‘./script.sh', into: '.'
              sshScript remote: remote, script: "doc.sh ${Username}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

getting below error while executing the script

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/script.sh Username does not exist.
```

Comment: DId you ever figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple pipeline script to show the usage of variable in bash script.

Pipeline script:

```yaml
pipeline {
   agent any
parameters {
    choice(name: 'stageparam', choices: ['build', 'deploy'], description: 'enter stageparam')
    string(name: 'USERNAME', defaultValue: 'abc', description: 'enter username')
  }
   stages {
      
      stage('Git Pull')
      {
         steps {
             checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitlab-test', url: 'http://localhost:8076/test-upgrade.git']]])
         } 
      }
      stage('Run the python script') {
          steps {
              sh 'chmod 777 test.py'
              sh "python test.py ${env.WORKSPACE}"
          }
      }
      stage('Run the bash script') {
          steps {
              sh 'chmod 777 run.sh'
              sh "./run.sh ${env.USERNAME}"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. My scenario is completely different. I want to execute my script in remote host using jenkins.